# What happens when AWS managed CMK is rotated (automatically), will my apps lose a connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rotation, key

Looking at the AWS documentation, I seem not to be able to find a very certain answer. I assume, if it happens automatically and the key alias is kept the same, there should not be any connectivity issues. Nevertheless, I would like to know for sure.

Comment: Will your apps lose a connection to what? How are you using the CMK exactly?

Comment: Mark B, thanks for the question. I haven't really explained the setup. Think of a production UI with a DB encrypted at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

No, your apps won't lose connectivity.  Automatic KMS CMK rotation is a safe thing to enable and won't affect your apps.

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html) has useful info:

> When you enable automatic key rotation for a customer managed CMK, AWS
> KMS generates new key material for the CMK every year. AWS KMS also
> saves the CMK's older key material in perpetuity so it can be used to
> decrypt data that it encrypted. AWS KMS does not delete any rotated
> key material until you delete the CMK.
>
> You do not need to change applications or aliases that refer to the
> key ID or key ARN of the CMK.